# ref.watch does not work on value changes to json_annotationed StateProvider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Provider

```
final userP =
    StateProvider<UserModel>((ref) => UserModel( null));
```

@JsonSerializable()
class UserModel {
String? intro;

UserModel(this.intro);

factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
_$UserModelFromJson(json);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserModelToJson(this);
}

Widget

```
final user = ref.watch(userP);
      Text(user.intro ?? 'innntro null?!'),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          ref.read(userP.notifier).state.intro = 'change!';
        },
        child: Text('change intro'))
      )
```

I have this riverpod provider and when I update the value with `ElevatedButton`, I see that it has been updated with `print()` value. However, it does not update the widget. It does that when I refresh the app with `pressing r on termianl`.

Is there a reason why and what am I doing it wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example, and when I change onPressed() like this it successfully updated

```
ref.read(userP.notifier).update((state) => UserModel('change'));
```